# Timed out receiving message from renderer in selenium Webdriver with Chrome Driver 87

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the following message in console log for the selenium web driver test run with chrome driver version 87:

Nov 20, 2020 12:14:58 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '500' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'timeout' (408 expected)
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000

I have following settings for chrome driver:

```
System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_SILENT_OUTPUT_PROPERTY,"true"); 
                        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ConstantResources.chromedriverpath);
                        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
                        options.addArguments("-disable-extensions");
                        options.addArguments("enable-automation"); 
                        options.addArguments("--disable-infobars"); 
                        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); 
                        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); 
                        options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation"); 
                        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
                        options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
                        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: using following in pom:   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
  </dependency>